# Windows 8 Store App how do you determine if a point is inside of your container?

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I am trying to move shapes around on a canvas using the ManipulationDelta.  It works but I am having an issue keeping them on my Canvas and by extension on the screen.  I was trying to somehow determine the bounds of my canvas and whether its X, Y is still on the canvas.  For instance, I was able to keep the Ellipse from being dragged off the top by setting Y to 0 when it is less than 0.

```
        void Shape1_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Ellipse shape = sender as Ellipse;
        TranslateTransform tt = shape.RenderTransform as TranslateTransform;
        tt.X += e.Delta.Translation.X;
        tt.Y += e.Delta.Translation.Y;

        if (tt.Y < 0)
            tt.Y = 0;

    }
```

The problem is that resolutions for screens differ and I can't figure out to determine the boundaries.  Is this right approach to take or is there a better way to allow users to drag items but keep them inside a defined area?

Thanks for any help you can give me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the Canvas is the same size as the screen (aka Window), then you can inspect Window.Current.Bounds for the size of the Window.

Comment: You sir are a scholar and a saint, that did the trick!  Might I ask how you would do it if the canvas were not the size of the screen?  Is there an equivalent method to get the bounds of a container such as a canvas or a grid?